# graph_tool pyside gtk 2.x and gtk 3.x

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyside

Environment: openSuSE 12.3 - Gnome

Error: 
When I execute my program, i get this:
"Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported
Trace/breakpoint trap"

Notice:

It occurs whenever I try to import at the same **PySide** and **graph_tool** modules.
To be more specific, whenever I import **draw** from **graph_tool** (which is the one that probably uses GTK+ 3.x)

**graph_tool**: http://graph-tool.skewed.de/

Problem:

I NEED the draw function AND PySide modules

So:

Is there a way to force PySide to use GTK+ 3.x styles instead of 2.x ones?
Or any other option to use both modules harmonically?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just solved:

```
from PySide import *
import gtk
import graph_tool.all as gt
```

By importing **gtk** itself, it apparently overrides any attempt from PySide submodules to use GTK+ 2.x namespaces.

Must be imported BEFORE graph_tool, apparently.